# Laravel eloquent not getting the results

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a laravel project and I don't see where is the bug here.

I have a products table with a "**low_stock_warning**" integer field and a "**units_stock**" integer field.

I want to get the products with a "**units_stock**" less than "**low_stock_warning**", so I have

```
$stock_warning = Product::whereRaw('units_stock <= low_stock_warning')
    ->select('id')
    ->get();
```

The result mysql is:

```
select `id` from `products` where units_stock <= low_stock_warning
```

If I execute it in my database directly I get one product. Ok, but Eloquent tells me that **$stock_warning** is an empty array...

What I'm missing here ?

Thanks!

[image]

**EDIT 1:**

I've tried with:

```
$stock_warning = Product::whereColumn('units_stock', '<=', 'low_stock_warning')->pluck('id');

print_r($stock_warning);
```

And the result is:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( ) )
```

**EDIT 2:**
This is the database structure:

```
--------------
DEVELOPMENT ENVIRONMENT
--------------
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                    | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| productdescriptioneng | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| units_stock           | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| low_stock_warning     | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

--------------
PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT
--------------
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                    | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| productdescriptioneng | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| units_stock           | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| low_stock_warning     | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Development**:
- Server version: 5.7.21 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

```
SHOW ENGINES;
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine             | Support | Comment                                                        | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| MEMORY             | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MRG_MYISAM         | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV                | YES     | CSV storage engine                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| BLACKHOLE          | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM             | YES     | MyISAM storage engine                                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     | Performance Schema                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| ARCHIVE            | YES     | Archive storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| InnoDB             | DEFAULT | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys     | YES          | YES  | YES        |
| FEDERATED          | NO      | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
```

**Production**:
- Server version: 5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu)

```
SHOW ENGINES;
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine             | Support | Comment                                                        | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| MyISAM             | YES     | MyISAM storage engine                                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MRG_MYISAM         | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV                | YES     | CSV storage engine                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| BLACKHOLE          | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     | Performance Schema                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| InnoDB             | DEFAULT | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys     | YES          | YES  | YES        |
| ARCHIVE            | YES     | Archive storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MEMORY             | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| FEDERATED          | NO      | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
```

Comment: Please show us structure and data for `products` table

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`whereColumn()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses) method:

```
Product::whereColumn('units_stock', '<=', 'low_stock_warning')->pluck('id')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but It is not working :(  (I haven't downvote anything)

Comment: @Klian what exactly do you mean by not working? Do you get an error or something? Also, please show the real data from the table.

Comment: I had tried to add the answer but @AlexeyMezenin have added first. I've same issue with comparing two column in database table before. It should work :D

Comment: I've added one screenshot and the laravel result

Comment: @Klian please show the real data from the table and exact columns types. Just tested this code with integers, works just fine.

Comment: The code is not working in development, but it works in production. I've reedited the main post with the database structure.

Comment: @Klian are you using a different kind of DB engine in a local environment?

Comment: I've updated the thread with my development and production engines and mysql version

Answer (score 0):

Verify if the product from DB is not soft deleted (deleted_at is not null);
if it is soft deleted, but you need them use this:

```
Product::whereColumn('units_stock', '<=', 'low_stock_warning')->withTrashed()->pluck('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use WhereColumn and orWhereColumn to achieve.

```
Product::whereColumn('units_stock', '<', 'low_stock_warning')
         orWhereColumn('units_stock', '=', 'low_stock_warning')   
        ->pluck('id');
```

Hope this helps